# Pushing to folder on GitHub

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to push some files from a local repo to a specific folder within a GitHub repo?

For example on my computer I have a folder called "folder". Within "folder" I have three files named "a" "b" and "c".

On GitHub I created a repository and when I push the three files to that repository I would like to have them in a folder inside the repo.

In other words I want to have the files on my PC at folder/ but on GitHub I would like to have them in folder/new-folder/.

Is this possible? If it is, how can I do it?

Comment: You could just have two separate GitHub projects and add folder/new-folder/* to your .gitignore for the top level local git repository.

Comment: Have you looked at `git subtree` and `git submodule`?